# How to send file with wget

Tags: file, cgi, wget, send

I am trying to send camera settings file through .cgi with wget. I have code

> wget --http-user=admin --http-password=aaa --post-file=file.bin
>   http://`192.168.1.54`/restore.cgi

but answer is : http request sent awaiting response... no data received. retrying.
do you have any ideas where can be problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are showing a file named 'file.bin', which would suggest it is a raw binary file. wget can only send URL-encoded data. You will need to reverse-engineer the form fields typically sent to restore.cgi and duplicate that format in 'file.bin'.

From wget(1):

> In particular, --post-file is not for transmitting files as form
>   attachments: those must appear as "key=value" data (with appropriate
>   percent-coding) just like everything else. Wget does not currently
>   support "multipart/form-data" for transmitting POST data; only
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: thank you very much, but i absoute didnt understand. i found this code at internet, but i dont know what to do

Comment: You need to edit your original posting with more information, specifically, what is in file.bin and what is expected by restore.cgi. If you can do that then I'm sure you will get a dozen great answers on here.